# Twilio FCM notification not delievered in ios swift

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, twilio-programmable-chat

I've integrated Firebase cloud message (FCM) in my app with p8 certficate and I'm getting notification through FCM.

I'm also using Twillio for integrating twillio conversation, but the problem is I'm not getting Notification from twillio FCM, I've only setup with FCM not APNS in twillio because we have already setup with Firebase cloud message,

1. How I'll get notification with the help of Twillio FCM?
2. Do we need to setup apns in twillio for getting notification?
3. I need a suggestion if any.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To send notifications to iOS devices from Twilio Conversations you will need to set up your APN Credentials within Twilio. Please follow [the documentation on enabling push notifications on iOS in Twilio Conversations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/ios/push-notifications-ios).

Comment: Is there any idea how to use FCM with Twillio?

Comment: Twilio uses FCM to send Android and web notifications and APN to send iOS notifications. So you will need to set up your APN credentials within Twilio for iOS notifications. I'm sure it's not too different to setting up your APN credentials in FCM.